# Inequality involving norm of matrix integral

Tags: matrices, integration, inequality, normed-spaces

This question seems basic but I could not find an answer. I have seen the inequality
$$\left\|\int_a^b x(t) dt \right\| \leq \int_a^b \left\| x(t) \right\| dt $$
where $x(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector function and $\|\cdot\|$ is a vector norm, and $a < b$.

I wonder if this also holds for matrices with induced norm, that is
$$\left\|\int_a^b X(t) dt \right\| \leq \int_a^b \left\| X(t) \right\| dt $$
where $X(t)$ is a matrix function and $\|\cdot\|$ is an induced matrix norm, and $a < b$.  If it is true, is there any reliable citation source?

Comment: By induced norm, you mean a norm of the form $\sup_{v\neq 0}\frac{||Av||}{||v||}$?

Comment: The space $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is just a finite dimensional vector space like any other, so you can directly apply the the triangle inequality to any matrix-valued function, with any norm, induced or not (actually you could even have non square matrices). Induced norm are useful when dealing with matrix product but there's none here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Riemann-integrals are good enough for you, then these inequalities are just the disguised triangle inequality (here with sloppy notation):
$$
\left\|\int_a^b X(t) dt \right\| 

= \left\| \lim_{\mathcal Z} \sum_{\mathcal Z}X(\xi)  \right\|

\leq  \lim_{\mathcal Z} \sum_{\mathcal Z} \left\| X(\xi)  \right\|


\leq \int_a^b \left\| X(t) \right\| dt$$

Comment: So is this inequality true for all matrix norms, not just induced norms?

Comment: I think so, look at http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/231-02-03/Lecture_Notes/chap4.pdf

Answer (score 3):

If $||\cdot||$ is given by $||A||=\sup_{v\neq 0}\frac{N(Av)}{N(v)}$ then we have for a fixed $v$
$$N\left(\int_a^bX(t)dtv\right)=N\left(\int_a^bX(t)vdt\right)\leq \int_a^bN\left(X(t)v\right)dt\leq \int_a^b||X(t)||N(v)dt$$
so $\|\int_a^b X(t)dt\|\leq \int_a^b||X(t)||dt$.

In fact more generally, if $f\colon [a,b]\to X$ where $(X,||\dot||$ is a Banach space then $\|\int_a^b f(t)dt\|\leq \int_a^b||f(t)||dt$. It can be showed using a corollary of Hahn-Banach theorem:
\begin{align*}\|\int_a^b f(t)dt\|&=\sup_{\varphi\in X',||\varphi||=1}\left|\varphi\left(\int_a^b f(t)dt\right)\right|\\
&=\sup_{\varphi\in X',||\varphi||=1}\left|\int_a^b \varphi\left(f(t)\right)dt\right|\\
&\leq \sup_{\varphi\in X',||\varphi||=1}\int_a^b \left|\varphi\left(f(t)\right)\right|dt\\
&\leq 
\sup_{\varphi\in X',||\varphi||=1}\int_a^b \|f(t)\|dt
\\
&=\int_a^b \|f(t)\|dt.
\end{align*}